# JSF 1.2 + Javascript + AJAX

Tags: javascript, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I use jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3. I've written the javascript fuction and want to use it as onclick on a4j:commandButton.

Function:

```
function simpleFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById('check').value;
    if(x != null){
        alert("NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

Form:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="check" value="myvalue" style="display: none"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{crossReferenceMsg.min3}" style="font-size: 11px; color:red; font-weight: bold"/><br/>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{crossReferenceMsg.searchName}" for="tbSearchFilter"
                       style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"/>
        <h:inputText id="tbSearchFilter" value="#{CrossReferenceBean.searchText}">
        </h:inputText>
        <a4j:commandButton id="btnSearchCrossReference"
                           onclick="simpleFunction()"
                           action="#{CrossReferenceBean.search}"
                           value="#{crossReferenceMsg.search}"
                           reRender="dvFilters"/>
        <rich:messages for="tbSearchFilter"/>
        <rich:hotKey key="return"
                     handler="#{rich:element('btnSearchCrossReference')}.click()"
                     selector="#dvSearchCrossReference"/>
    </h:form>
```

But it does not work - in GoogleChrome debugger I can see, that variable x = undefined. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

add `prependId="false"` to your `h:form`.

in this case, by default, form id (something like j_idt..., which is automatically set by jsf) is prepended to all the component ids nested in your form. so your actual `h:inputText` id is not "check". you can see that if you inspect html source of your page.